# RestKit ios nested objects of same type

Tags: ios, xml-parsing, restkit

how can i map nested objects of the same type?
i have an xml with objects that may contain multiple objects of the same type:

```
<entry location="l1">
    <entry location="l1.1">
        <entry location="l1.1.1">
        </entry>
        <entry location="l1.1.2">
        </entry>
    </entry>
</entry>
```

i get an infinite recursion if i add a propertymapping with the same mapping:

```
+ (RKObjectMapping *)objectMapping {
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Entry class]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"location": @"location"}];
    [mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"nextEntries"
                                                                            toKeyPath:@"entries"
                                                                          withMapping:[Entry objectMapping]]];

    return mapping;
}
```

is it possible to add the sub-objects to an array of each parent object?

cheers

**//edit**: following code works for me:

```
+ (RKObjectMapping *)objectMapping
{
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Entry class]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"location": @"location"}];

    RKObjectMapping *innerMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Entry class]];
    [innerMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"location": @"location"}];

    [mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping
        relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"entry"
        toKeyPath:@"entries"
        withMapping:innerMapping]];

    return mapping;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it so I don't know if it will work but try this:

```
+ (RKObjectMapping *)objectMapping
{
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Entry class]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"location": @"location"}];

    RKObjectMapping *innerMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Entry class]];
    [innerMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"location": @"location"}];

    [mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping
        relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"nextEntries"
        toKeyPath:@"entries"
        withMapping:innerMapping]];

    return mapping;
}
```

Not sure that `toKeyPath:@"entries"` is correct, it may need to be `toKeyPath:@"entry"` based on your XML.

The infinite recursion is because you're calling the same method from itself (`[Entry objectMapping]`), it has nothing to do with the mapping as such.

Comment: Please accept answers that are correct / help you solve the issue. Thanks :)